# Pass value into a textbox (on another page) using a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Relatively new to JavaScript. Here is what I am trying to do:

1.) User clicks on hyperlink

2.) User is redirected to www.blah.com (a site I don't own)

3.) A value that is stored in the URL populates a textbox box.

BONUS:

4.) After the value is entered in the textbox, a named button is automatically activated to search for the entered string

I know if the textbox is in the SAME webpage as the hyperlink I can do something like:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('THEID').value='blah';">THELINK</a>
```

How do I do this to another page?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that for security reasons. If it was a site that you DO own, then it is possible using URL parameters.

Comment: If you don't own the other website, you can't control what they do with URLs.  It's easy enough to do what you want using a query string, but the other website needs to be set up to read the string and do something with the data.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that for a site you don't own, security issues. You can use GreaseMonkey scripts on chrome if this is more of a hack